# How do I specify OpenApiParameter properties for OBJECT type?

Tags: python, django, drf-spectacular

In drf-yasg when we specify Schema we have properties argument, where we can specify fields of OBJECT type.
How do I get the same behavior for drf-spectacular's OpenApiParameter?

```py
    @swagger_auto_schema(
        summary="Wallet balance",
        description="Save the wallet's balance",
        request=openapi.Schema(
            type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT, properties={
                'balance': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_NUMBER),
                'some_object': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_OBJECT, properties={
                    'a': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
                    'b': openapi.Schema(type=openapi.TYPE_STRING),
                }),
            }
        ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This variant fixed my problem

```py
            OpenApiParameter(
                name='location',
                description='Current page location',
                required=True,
                type={
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': {
                        'host': {'type': 'number'},
                        'pathname': {'type': 'string'},
                    },
                }
            ),
```